# How to write namespace for folder name with hyphen in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

My Folder structure like this core/options/control/text-control/text-control.php

For **text-control.php** I used this namespace.

```
Core\Options\Control\Text_Control
```

and the class name **Text_Control** 
I also tried this namespace

```
Core\Options\Control\TextControl
```

and the class name **TextControl** . 
When I try this code

```
<?php
if (class_exists('Core\Options\Control\TextControl\TextControl')) {

    echo 'Class found';

} else {

    echo 'Class not found';
}
```

The class does not found

But If I try this folder structure like this core/options/control/text/text.php
And namespace like this `Core\Options\Control\Text` and class name **Text** then I can find the class.
So how to deal with **'-'** in folder name? I hope you got my point.

N.B: I am using composer for autoloading

Comment: can you show your autoloader code?

Comment: I used the composer. Everything working fine as expected except the '-' folder name

Comment: then you need to follow https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/